# "По Далю" - следует ли выделять запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

Ув. филологи! Стоит ли выделять запятой "по Далю"? Можно ли где-то правило найти?
А также необходимо ли цитату из словаря в этом случае начать с большой буквы? Спасибо!

По Далю, «лень – это неохота работать, отвращенье от труда, от дела, занятий; наклонность к праздности, к тунеядству».

Answer (score 3):

Да, стоит, это вводное слово, указывающее на источник сообщения = как писал Даль:   http://www.lingvotech.com/vvod

Цитата с маленькой, строчной буквы, потому что вставлена в предложение, это не начало другого предложения и не прямая речь.